# IOErrors for regular expression in python

Tags: python, regex

I've been working on a program, but due to Mac OS X's difficulties in updating python, I've been doing it in both 3.2 and 2.6, nevertheless, both versions of the script give me IOErrors (they're different though). Here's the script:

This is the 3.2 version:

```
import sys
import os 
import re 
import urllib 
import urllib.request

## opens the URL as a bytes object
urlfilebytes = urllib.request.urlopen('http://www.reddit.com/r/fffffffuuuuuuuuuuuu')
## saves the bytes object to a string
urlfile = urlfilebytes.read().decode('utf-8'))
## saves list of matches for pattern
matches = re.findall(r'[http://imgur.com/][\s]+"', open(urlfile).read())
```

This returns the error:
TypeError: invalid file:

The 2.6 version on the other hand:

```
import sys
import os
import re
import urllib
urlfilebytes = urllib.urlopen('http://www.reddit.com/r/fffffffuuuuuuuuuuuu')
urlfile = urlfilebytes.read().decode('utf-8')
matches = re.findall(r'[http://imgur.com/][\s]+"', open(urlfile).read())
```

This returns the error:

```
IOError: [Errno 63] File name too long: u'<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en" ><head><title>FFFFFFFUUUUUUUUUUUU-</title><meta name="keywords" content=" r **ETC ETC ETC**
```

I'm kind of stumped here, can anyone help me out?

Comment: Why are you calling `open` on the contents of that webpage? Doesn't make any sens.

Comment: Also, look to macports to get Py2.7 working fine on OSX.

Comment: I wasn't earlier and that gave me an error, so I read some documentation and called open.

Comment: Side note: the Fink package manager offers very recent versions of Python (at least in its [very stable] "unstable" branch) and of many harder-to-compile Python module.

Comment: The problem was I already updated everything, just I couldn't access python 3.2 from the command line, I just realized now I can do this by typing python3.2 instead of just python. Do you know how to map python to python3.2? I followed the man page's instructions for updating the versioner but that did nothing.

Comment: You probably have a symbolic link `python` in your /usr/bin directory (or mac equivalent, I'm not familiar with the directory structure of macs). You can update this link by calling `ln -sf <path_to_python3.2> /usr/bin/python`. You can find the paths with the command `which`, for instance `which python` will give you the path to the symlink, and `which python3.2` where the python executable resides.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure you don't want to just do this?

```
re.findall(r'[http://imgur.com/][\s]+"', urlfile)
```

And I bet the regexp doesn't do what you think it does. Perhaps you need to ask another question about that

Perhaps something like this

```
re.findall(r'(http://imgur.com/\S+)"', urlfile)
```

or this

```
re.findall(r'http://imgur.com/(\S+)"', urlfile)
```

Comment: Duly noted, the list I got back was, uh, ...not expected.

Comment: Yes- worked, I'd had it doing non-whitespace earlier, but somewhere in the copy/pasting looks like it got messed up. Thank you so much for your help! the script works perfectly now!

Answer (score 3):

You call `open` on the string, which tries to open a file named whatever the string contains. In this case `<!DOCTYPE...`. And that is not a valid filename or existing file. If you replace `open(urlfile).read()` with just `urlfile`, it should work.

Also, you might want to escape the `[]`s in the regexp, or it won't do what you want.

Comment: Thanks for your help! But now I'm getting
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'

Comment: Also- the brackets are not in the string literal, I was using them to indicate a set of chars

Comment: @rab777hp, you'll want to remove the `read()` part too, sorry if that wasn't clear from the above.

Comment: The only problem now is, as gnibbler pointed out, the regex does not due what I thought it'd do, list of single letters and /', I'm *definitely* doing something very wrong here.